# Protect iPad settings

Tags: ipad

I am developing a web application to be run in iPad safari. The iPads will be provided to the customers and the question is - I want to allow access only to the safari browser and not other applications that can be found in the iPad, especially the iPad settings. Is there anyway I can do that in iPad?

Comment: Are you allowed to jailbreak the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically talking about turning the iPad into a kiosk, meaning a computer that cannot be controlled locally beyond a subset of chosen functionality.  In other words, the user is not in charge.  In practice, every iPhone and iPad is a kiosk, because Apple is in charge.  The only way to take control away from Apple is to jailbreak the device.

The extent to which Apple is willing to share the reins is the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) which does not allow you to disable settings, although you can disable Safari.